# PHP awkward behavoir when reading from a text file. Variable reading BLANK

Tags: php, text-files

A string I'm working with in PHP comes from a text file and the line reads:

```
<Unknown>
```

However when I `var_dump` the array variable associated to this line, it reads

```
string(9) ""
```

I've inserted the same data `<Unknown>` before into MySQL and have never had this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are `var_dump`ing it and using your web browser to see the output, anything between `<` and `>` is regarded as a HTML tag by your browser, thus you see no output but with `string(9)`

You can try:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($var, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to surely see:)))

```
$var = "<unknown>";
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($var));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php